# Switching to another SQLite database after user purchases the full version

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm building an app that teaches English words. The trial version of the app will contain 40 words, and the full version will contain about 2000. I will keep these two as separate databases in assets folder, when the user first downloads the app it will copy the trial database and use it. After the user buys the full version the app will replace the old database with the full one. When the user goes pro, the app will keep user scores on every word so I need database to stand where it is, as unchanged after going full.

This is my basic approach to the problem:

```
boolean fullVersionCopied = false;

if(purchase != true && database doesn't exists)
   Copy the trial database from the assets folder.

else(purchase == true && !fullVersionCopied){
   try{
        Copy the full version database
        fullVersionCopied = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        fullVersionCopied = false;

    }
}
```

Now I've a few questions. Is this a good approach to do what I want or are there any better ways to do this?

The app will generate an unique random int everytime and use the int to find a word by its id number. I've never worked with databases before. Does it takes lot of time to find a row among 2000 other rows? I will try to make this searching in a different thread but should I divide such a huge database to smaller pieces for granting speed to my app?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: any reason why you don't want to save the 2000 words into the database (2000 rows is pretty small for sqlite)? let the free version generate int 0-40, and the full version generate from 0 to 2000? it seems so much easier to implement.

Comment: Yes you are right! Thank you you are a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good approach to do?

So far NO, You only need a single database for your app since you can just limit the number of rows fetched. In your case there is no actual advantage of using 2 separate database, it will just add a headache in the maintenance later on.

Here is an example query of limiting

```
SELECT * FROM wordstable LIMIT 40
```

> Does it takes lot of time to find a row among 2000 other rows?

There are many ways to overcome the massive complexity, one of the convenient way of doing this is by the help of [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), it handles the query in a separate Thread behind the scene.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about limiting the rows fetched but will learn more about it.